# Basic Python Lists

Tags: python

I needed help on how to find which test has the lowest number. This code will help explain.

```
test_list=[]
numbers_list=[]

while True:
    test=raw_input("Enter test or (exit to end): ")
    if test=="exit":
        break
    else:
        test_numbers=input("Enter number: ")
        test_list.append(test)
        numbers_list.append(test_numbers)
```

If `test_list=['Test1','Test2','Test3']` and `numbers_list=[2,1,3]`

How would I print that Test2 has the lowest number? Since Test2 = 1

Comment: Are they all integers?

Comment: If you have an array of keys and and array of values then a dictionary is a much better data type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Find the index `i` in `numbers_list` corresponding to the smallest element:

   - [Python: Find index of minimum item in list of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13300962/139010)
   - [Python Finding Index of Maximum in List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530799/139010)
   - [Efficient way to get index of minimum value in long vector, python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6044645/139010)
   - [How to find all positions of the maximum value in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3989016/139010)
2. Retrieve `test_list[i]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip` to zip them together:

```
>>> zip(numbers_list, test_list)
[(2, 'Test1'), (1, 'Test2'), (3, 'Test3')]
```

Then use `min` to find the smallest pair:

```
>>> min(zip(numbers_list, test_list))
(1, 'Test2')
```

Finally, you can split the pair up:

```
>>> number, test = min(zip(numbers_list, test_list))
>>> number      
1
>>> test
'Test2'
```

Comment: +1, but I have a feel the OP was asking for homework so `zip` and friends might not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be looking to use a dictionary.  It would look something like this..

```
aDict = {'1':'meh','2':'foo'}

sortedDict = sorted(aDict)

lowestValue = sortedDict[0]

print lowestValue
```